# I have to import a numpy file (npy) to a scrypt (.py 2.7), don't know how?

Tags: numpy, python-2.7, file

I have a numpy file that I can't share, that has to be imported in a python 2.7 (yes ... I need to work with 2.7 for this...) and I dont know how to do this, or how to know if it's recognized or how to see whats inside.

Can some one explain, please how can I see what's inside the numpy file, and how to call it from the script?

Thanks ;)

I've tried importing it, but it doesn't find it

edited: I've tried with this: `np.load('preflop.ea.npy')` But doesn't seem to work (I've tried to print it and it doesn't print).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JttYP.png)

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" does not help us help you.  A `npy` is supposed to be loaded with `np.load`, not `imported`.  It isn't a code file; it's a binary file that contains a numpy array.  You can't see "whats inside it" without that `load`.

Comment: @hpaulj it doesnt print ... so don't know if it's ok or not

Comment: The `np.load` function returns a numpy array (or error).  It doesn't print anything (automatically).  Have you worked with `python` or `numpy` before?

Comment: I use numpy ... but never used a numpy file before

Comment: `np.save` and `np.load` have good doc pages